# Ffmpeg lose streams while using -map 0

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

I had a strange issue using ffmpeg on Ubuntu 14.04.
I run a command

```
ffmpeg -i output2.avi -c:v h264 -minrate 2000k -maxrate 5000k -bufsize 2000k -profile:v high -level:v 4 -coder 1 -s 640x360 -bf 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -g 25 -c:a aac -ar 48k -b:a 321k -map 0 -y outpu.mp4
```

It provides such a usual output in console (already with -loglevel verbose):

```
ffmpeg version N-79004-g2e6636a Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers


 built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/ngoral/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/ngoral/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/ngoral/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/ngoral/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 28.101 / 57. 28.101
  libavformat    57. 28.101 / 57. 28.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 39.102 /  6. 39.102
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[avi @ 0x2707800] parser not found for codec dvvideo, packets or times may be invalid.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Input #0, avi, from 'output2.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.28.101
  Duration: 00:00:20.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 28911 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: dvvideo, 1 reference frame (dvsd / 0x64737664), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 28684 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:3: Audio: aac ([255][0][0][0] / 0x00FF), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 117 kb/s
Matched encoder 'libx264' for codec 'h264'.
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x2784f60] w:720 h:576 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/25 fr:25/1 sar:16/15 sws_param:flags=2
[scaler for output stream 0:0 @ 0x2749d20] w:640 h:360 flags:'bicubic' interl:0
[scaler for output stream 0:0 @ 0x2749d20] w:720 h:576 fmt:yuv420p sar:16/15 -> w:640 h:360 fmt:yuv420p sar:3/4 flags:0x4
[graph 1 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x27a4fc0] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:s16p samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[audio format for output stream 0:1 @ 0x27a5380] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted resampler 0' between the filter 'Parsed_anull_0' and the filter 'audio format for output stream 0:1'
[auto-inserted resampler 0 @ 0x27a7ae0] ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:s16p r:48000Hz -> ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:fltp r:48000Hz
[graph 2 input from stream 0:2 @ 0x27a6620] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:s16p samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[audio format for output stream 0:2 @ 0x27a6440] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted resampler 0' between the filter 'Parsed_anull_0' and the filter 'audio format for output stream 0:2'
[auto-inserted resampler 0 @ 0x27b6be0] ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:s16p r:48000Hz -> ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:fltp r:48000Hz
[graph 3 input from stream 0:3 @ 0x27b6560] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[libx264 @ 0x27889a0] using SAR=3/4
[libx264 @ 0x27889a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x27889a0] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x27889a0] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=2 keyint=25 keyint_min=2 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=25 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=5000 vbv_bufsize=2000 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'outpu.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.28.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), -1 reference frame ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 3:4 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, max. 5000 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.28.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 5000000/0/0 buffer size: 2000000 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 321 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.28.101 aac
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 321 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.28.101 aac
    Stream #0:3: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 321 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.28.101 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (dvvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp3 (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (mp3 (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
*** 3 dup!
No more output streams to write to, finishing.e=00:00:19.84 bitrate= 359.9kbits/s dup=3 drop=0 speed=1.15x
frame=  501 fps= 29 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1792kB time=00:00:20.05 bitrate= 732.2kbits/s dup=3 drop=0 speed=1.14x
video:440kB audio:1331kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.155376%
Input file #0 (output2.avi):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 498 packets read (71712000 bytes); 498 frames decoded;
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 834 packets read (480384 bytes); 834 frames decoded (960768 samples);
  Input stream #0:2 (audio): 835 packets read (160320 bytes); 835 frames decoded (961920 samples);
  Input stream #0:3 (audio): 0 packets read (0 bytes); 0 frames decoded (0 samples);
  Total: 2167 packets (72352704 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (outpu.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 501 frames encoded; 501 packets muxed (451055 bytes);
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 939 frames encoded (960768 samples); 940 packets muxed (724261 bytes);
  Output stream #0:2 (audio): 940 frames encoded (961920 samples); 941 packets muxed (639072 bytes);
  Output stream #0:3 (audio): 0 frames encoded (0 samples); 0 packets muxed (0 bytes);
  Total: 2382 packets (1814388 bytes) muxed
[libx264 @ 0x27889a0] frame I:21    Avg QP:15.30  size:  8718
[libx264 @ 0x27889a0] frame P:480   Avg QP:24.52  size:   557
[libx264 @ 0x27889a0] mb I  I16..4: 20.4% 55.5% 24.1%
[libx264 @ 0x27889a0] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  P16..4:  7.6%  3.7%  1.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:86.8%
[libx264 @ 0x27889a0] 8x8 transform intra:56.3% inter:50.3%
[libx264 @ 0x27889a0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 42.0% 39.5% 27.5% inter: 2.6% 1.4% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x27889a0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 36% 52%  3% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x27889a0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 56% 20% 14%  2%  1%  1%  2%  2%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x27889a0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 42% 26%  7%  4%  3%  4%  5%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x27889a0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 66% 13% 17%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x27889a0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x27889a0] ref P L0: 68.1% 11.5% 13.9%  6.5%
[libx264 @ 0x27889a0] kb/s:179.78
[aac @ 0x2747da0] Qavg: 62719.090
[aac @ 0x2748b20] Qavg: 64509.496
[aac @ 0x27498a0] Qavg: -nan
```

it seems like it outputs all 3 audiostreams, but then i do

```
ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -i outpu.mp4
```

And get only 2 audiostreams:

```
ffmpeg version N-79004-g2e6636a Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/ngoral/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/ngoral/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/ngoral/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/ngoral/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 28.101 / 57. 28.101
  libavformat    57. 28.101 / 57. 28.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 39.102 /  6. 39.102
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'outpu.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.28.101
  Duration: 00:00:20.06, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 731 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High), 3 reference frames (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 (640x368) [SAR 3:4 DAR 4:3], 180 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 289 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 254 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

What's wrong with it?
It works fine on my Win machine, on virtual machine with Ubuntu on it, but as ran on real Ubuntu it behaves like this. Do you have any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recheck your input file to see if the 3rd audio stream is valid. Your ffmpeg encode output says.

```
Input stream #0:3 (audio): 0 packets read (0 bytes); 0 frames decoded (0 samples);
```

and hence

```
Output stream #0:3 (audio): 0 frames encoded (0 samples); 0 packets muxed (0 bytes);
```

---

Copy just the 3rd stream and see if it works

```
ffmpeg -i output2.avi -c copy -map 0:a:2 test.avi
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't mention it!
And how could i check it? I know only `ffmpeg -i output2.avi`

Comment: Run the command I gave and play the output.

Comment: Sorry, miss your answer edition.
`Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)` was what it said. It looks like input file is badly encoded, but i can't understand why.
It was encoded from three files with a command `ffmpeg -i input1.avi -i audio1.mp3 -t 00:00:20 -i audio2.aac -t 00:00:20 -c copy -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -y output2.avi`.
And again: on Win your command ran without any problems

Comment: In `-t 00:00:20 -i audio2.aac -t 00:00:20`, the first `t` parameter is not needed.

Comment: Yes, after that it worked fine!
And how could it be explained? Both things: that the key `-t` is not needed and that on Win it works fine?

Comment: Looks like there's no explanation to it:) Ok, at least now I know where's the problem.